# How to redirect to home page of Pentaho after basic authentication in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, spring, authentication, pentaho

I try to use basic authentication in VB.NET side to login Pentaho

I use the default account of Pentaho for testing

username: joe

password: password

I have following code in VB.NET for basic authentication to Pentaho

```
Dim request = WebRequest.Create("http://x.x.x.x:8080/pentaho/Home")
Dim authInfo As String = Convert.ToString(userName) & ":" & Convert.ToString(userPassword)
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(authInfo))
request.Headers("Authorization") = "Basic " & authInfo
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

After ran the **request.GetResponse()** can get the successful result. So I think the Pentaho login and authentication successfully

But when I go to http://x.x.x.x:8080/pentaho/Home Pentaho still prompt to Login Page…

Do You know What wrong of my code?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do here. Where are you going to pentaho/Home. In your code ?

If you want to programatically call a certain URL in Pentaho, it's probably easier to append the credentials to the query string.

Comment: Thanks your response. you can see that the code `Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()`  the variable **response** can get the response result from pentaho successfully. so I assume the authentication passed at that code. But when I go to home page of pentaho, pentaho still prompt the login page...

Comment: so I want to ask how to redirect to home page of pentaho after the authentication complete and success?  thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Basic Authentication method, I already answered this question in bellow post.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159579/pentaho-authentication-method-in-silver-light-application/31855955#31855955)

Eg-

```
WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://serverDomain:8080/pentaho/Home");
//Give user name and password here
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
var encodedString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + encodedString;
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
App.WindowManager.ConsoleWrite(uri.ToString());
webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", "");
```