# Pentaho Authentication Method in Silver light Application.

Tags: c#, silverlight, pentaho

I want to integrate Pentaho with Silverlight platform.For the Authentication, there is log in page for user console. I do not want use above login page to login, I want to login in code behind.

I tried basic authentication, but in new version it won't work.

```
 string[] parts = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(ae.Result, "/");
                    String data = "userid=" + App.UserName + "&password=" + App.Password;
                    WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Home?" + data);
                    webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    App.WindowManager.ConsoleWrite(uri.ToString());
                    webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", "");
```

But its worked with previous version of Pentaho. I know there are few other methods available in Pentaho. But it should able to do in Silverlight application.
do you know any other solution for do it in Silverlight Application ?

Thanks you very much in advance!!!

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authenticate with query string method is unsecured one, so I found a solution with Basic Authentication method.

```
WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://serverDomain:8080/pentaho/Home");
//Give user name and password here
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
var encodedString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + encodedString;
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
App.WindowManager.ConsoleWrite(uri.ToString());
webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In previous version we could pass userid=admin&password=password as part of URL while calling prpt, xaction or Analyzer.

In 5.0 we can authenticate via URL only to Home page.

Try the following to enable it.

i) Stop your Bi server. 

 ii) Open applicationContext-spring-security.xml and look for filterChainProxy bean. 

 iii) Comment the existing value section in the bean and add the new value section provided below.

```
 <value>
        <![CDATA[CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
        PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
        /api/repos/dashboards/print=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,preAuthenticatedSecurityFilter,httpSessionReuseDetectionFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor
        /webservices/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /api/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /plugin/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionReuseDetectionFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor]]>
      </value>
```

iv) Restart your server, you should be able to call a report or xaction with user credientials in the url.

v) Use this test URL http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:public:Steel%20Wheels:Buyer%20Report%20%28sparkline%20report%29.prpt/viewer?userid=admin&password=password

Comment: Marlon Abeykoon,
Thank you for your answer, with your answer now I can authenticate using query string method. But it's not secure that can find the password easily from web browser. Do you know other solution for this.