# How to integrate Pentaho reporting in .NET webapi application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, pentaho, birt

I have a requirement to integrate pentaho with my .NET application.

I already have .Net application.It is succesfully running in production.Now we want to integrate pentaho with existing application.I dont want to call pentaho webservice.I should integrate with in my application.Is it posssible?

Can anyone guide me the possibility of integration or alternatives to proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of a integration you look for?  you can check my answer on authentication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159579/pentaho-authentication-method-in-silver-light-application/29208264#29208264

Comment: I already have .Net application.It is succesfully running in production.Now we want to integrate pentaho with existing application.I dont want to call pentaho webservice.I should integrate with in my application.Is it posssible?